# Линковка товаров и категорий

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть проблема, в сайдбар плагином вывожу меню категорий и подкатегорий товаров. Ссылка имеет вот такой вид

http://megapolis.bz/product-category/spetsodejda/zashitnyaya-spetsodejda/odejda-dlya-svarshikov/

Проблема в том, что ссылка на товар имеет другой вид

http://megapolis.bz/shop/spetsodejda/zashitnyaya-spetsodejda/kostyum-svarshhika-zimnij-kurtka-bryuki-brezentovyj/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То-есть, в категориях идет product-category, а в товарах shop. Из-за этого если перейти в нужную мне категорию, то товаров там попросту нету. Как это в общему виду привести ?

Comment: Ссылки у вас правильные. "Из-за этого если перейти в нужную мне категорию, то товаров там попросту нету". Как это? Что-то вы сломали в WooCommerce

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста, я добавил реальные ссылки на категорию и товар. В самом товаре, категории я правильно выставил. Что не так вот с этими ссылками ? и куда смотреть хотя бы ? спасибо

Comment: Что-то не так с указанием категорий товара. Из товара можно же выйти на "Спецодежда" и "Защитная спецодежда"

Comment: добавил скриншот, в самом товаре я правильно категории указал. Или вы что-то другое имели ввиду ?

Comment: Я заметил, что в ссылке на товар, не отображается последняя категория, может в этом дело

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что вы используете старый плагин Easy Sidebar Menu Widget. Он не обновлялся больше года. За это время в WooCommerce много воды утекло, появилась 3 версия. отключите его (и остальные тоже) и поробуйте перейти из товара в последнюю категорию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75768/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-denis-denis).

Comment: Я понял, вы бы не могли мне подсказать, какой-нибудь другой плагин, для решения моей задачи ?

Comment: Сначала надо убедиться, что проблема в этом плагине

Answer (score 0):

Проблема было в том, что в самом woocommerce не было настроено отображение подкатегорий и товаров.

Перейдите в раздел "Внешний Вид" -> "Настроить" -> "Woocommerce" -> "Product Catalog" -> и тут нужно выбрать настройку "Отображать подкатегории и товары"

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом. У меня сайты с иерархией категорий работают правильно, если указанная вами настройка стоит по умолчанию: Показывать товары

Comment: К сожалению вы правы. Мне получается нужно, чтобы в подкатегориях выводился товар. Он почему-то скрыт. Пробовал поставить чистую тему, там все работает. Получается либо сама тема не поддерживает это, либо какой-то конфликт идёт